# Can't make div fill width of screen in Webkit (chrome and safari)

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit, cross-browser

I have a div that I want to use as the page footer, and have it fill the whole width of the page. So far, so simple, you would think. And, it is, in *Firefox* and IE.

Unfortunately in both major webkit browsers, despite having my footer (`#footer`) set for `width:100%; max-width:none;`, webkit won't make it fill the width of the browser window.

The page is here: [page demonstrating problem](http://kitandmarcin.us/tustincommercial/index.xhtml)

What's happening? Any solutions?

Edit: Apologies all - when I said it was working in Safari, that was a typo - I meant firefox.

Screenshots:

**Here it is working in IE:**
[image: Working correctly in IE]

Here it is being broken in Chrome (same behaviour in Safari). The arrow is hand drawn, for emphasis.
[image: Broken rendering in Chrome]

Comment: is it `width:100;` or `width:100%`? However, I tested your site on chrome, it's working there.

Comment: Same here. A screenshot would be nice (and what do you mean by **major webkit browsers**? Safari is webkit, and so is Chrome, so webkit seems to be working fine).

Comment: Naveed - apologies - It's 100% (omitting the % was a typo in the question).

Comment: seems like it's all working now?

Comment: @Blowski - I fixed the CSS as below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the following line, without the comments, was causing problems:

```
#footer {  position: fixed;  bottom:0; left: 0; /*max-width: 11400px; max-width: none; width: 11400px;*/ width: 100%;  height:75pt;}
```

For some reason WebKit saw the `max-width: 11400px; max-width: none; width: 11400px;` and set the width to something like half the screen size.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is probably that the footer has some parent element with `position:` set to anything. This creates what is known as a stacking context. If you put your footer in the body or inside an element the size of the entire viewport, then 100% will truly be 100% of the viewport.

edit: Apparently this is not your answer, just what is usually the answer in 99% of cases, so I include it for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I run Chrome, and it works fine for me. Can you post a screenshot?

Besides that, your content is a bit off, so here's a fix for that:

```
#body-row {
  padding-left: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo: `width:100%;`

edit: typo now seems to be fixed

Answer (score 0):

in

```
#footer {
max-width:none;
}
```

this is not a valid deceleration, since it is not valid, it is being overwritten by

```
.row {
max-width: 1140px;
}
```

to solve:

change

```
#footer{
max-width:100%
}
```

done!

Comment: None is a valid value for max-width: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-max-width

Answer (score -1):

The `position:fixed` on `#footer` is causing that.

Are you using Firebug in Firefox? That will help you to debug much more quickly. Also, consider using a framework like 960gs together with Paul Irish's HTML5 Boilerplate as a good base on which to build.

Comment: It works just fine in firefox and IE, and I want `position:fixed` behaviour. I absolutely do not want to use a fixed-width layout, not even a "fluid" layout that has a maximum width.

Comment: 960gs has a fluid option with no max-width - and you can add a `position:fixed` to a container. HTML5 Boilerplate helps by resetting all browsers to a standard CSS, which helps avoid cross-browser bugs, and a lot of other best practice stuff to get you going. You don't _need_ it to solve this problem, but you may find it speeds up your development time.